# Limit the width of <body> but use full width if window is to small

Tags: html, css, layout, viewport

I have seen this before somewhere but couldn't find it again to take a look at it.
So let me give you my own example.

[image]

The `<body>` (lightblue) here has a width of `55vw` (55% of the viewport width).
This is OK for me as long the window (viewport) is wide enough. But when it becomes to small (the width of the viewport decrease) I would like the `<body>` to take the full viewpower width (`100vw`).

I remember that I have seen a website behaving like that. But I can't find an example currently.

This picture describe the problem. The width of the browser window is much smaller but the body still has `55vw`.

[image]

But the expected result should be like this

[image]

Here is a full MWE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html {
                background-color: lightgreen;
            }

            body {
                background-color: lightblue;
                width: 55vw;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            main {
                background-color: orange;
                margin: 1em;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It sets a breakpoint at 600px. Above that, it'll stretch to 55vw, at 600px it'll go full size. It'll give you a fairly smooth transition effect as you shrink to a smaller screen size.

**edited to add**
At small screen sizes (less than 600px), the rule is, effectively min(100%, 600px). Since 100% of the screen width is less than 600px, the 100% number 'wins' so the element is 100% of the screen width.

At greater than 600px, the rule is, effectively max(600px, 55vw). At approximately 600-1200px, the 600px number 'wins' so the width is 600px. At large screen sizes (approx > 1200px) 55vw is wider than 600px so that one wins.

This can be rewritten as `width: clamp(55vw,600px,100%);`. There's info on [clamp on CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/use-css-clamp-to-create-a-more-flexible-wrapper-utility/)

**end of edit**

Information on min on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min). Max is just the same but the other way round. There's an article that's probably easier to understand on [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/min-max-and-clamp-are-css-magic/)

```css
html {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: min(100%,max(600px, 55vw));
  margin: 0 auto;
}

main {
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Fascinating. Never seen a construct like that. Can you please explain a bit more and/or add references to the W3C docu or somewhere else?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the post with references

Comment: You may also be interested in the [CSS `clamp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp) function.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get how this min-max construct works together. Can you break them down step by step? How does `min()` know that its first argument `100%` must be used when the first argument of the other function `max()` is reached?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use media queries to get your desired result. Suppose you want the body to take full width when the screen is 600px. So you will do it like this:-

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
  body{
     width: 100vw;
}}
```