How to get specifically positioned divs to correctly resize based on browser width
Is there a way to have a div container scale down responsively as soon the the container starts hitting the browser sides (if browser is made smaller)... rather than only doing it once it hits a media query width setting?
Currently my containers get cut off either the left or right side, and it's only "fixed" once the media queries kicks into set margins to 0. any ideas?
I have put the code below into a snippet.
It may be better to view the snipper when you expand the snippet to full size, and adjusting browser width to be smaller to see how things get cutoff.


body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}


/* Link styles */

a {
  color: blue;
  /* Set link color to blue */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Remove default underline */
}


/* Hover and active link styles */

a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
  /* Underline link on hover, click, or focus */
}

.container {
  background-color: ;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Change flex direction to column */
  position: relative;
  /* Add position relative */
  margin-top: 0px;
  /* Add margin-top for spacing */
}


/* Custom CSS for text boxes */

.textbox {
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  /* Add margin-top for spacing */
  margin-left: auto;
  /* Align to the right */
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  /* Add margin-bottom for spacing */
  text-align: left;
  /* Align text to the left */
}


/* Media query for positioning and scaling the second container */

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .first-container,
  .second-container {
    margin-left: 0;
    /* Reset margin-left */
    margin-right: 0;
    /* Reset margin-left */
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .first-container {
    margin-left: 8%;
    /* Position from the left */
  }
  .second-container {
    margin-right: 8%;
    /* Position from the right */
  }
}
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container first-container" style="max-width: 800px">
  <div style="background-color: orange; width: 100%">
    Content / text/ images
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>

  <div class="textbox">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container second-container" style="max-width: 600px">
  <div style="background-color: lightcoral; width: 100%">
    Content / text/ images
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>

  <div class="textbox">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>




Try using css flex property alongside min and max width

hi there, thaks for the suggestion. any chance you can point me to an example (pretty new to coding). do you mean adding a flexbox around everything?

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp. May be this can help
In Addition read this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox

thank you for those. i had a look, and have played a bit with flexbox before. i'm not sure this entirely solves the issue, as although flex gives control on scaling - the problem i have is that the boxes are positioned to be e.g. 10% from the left, or 8% from the right. it's ensuring that if the browser width is reduced and they hit the edge either side they start scaling down responsively (and switch to margin 0) when that moment happens instead of only when a media query is triggered
sorry if i've misunderstood - any examples appreciated, thank you.

Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75109548/12571484

Not too sure of the result you are exepcting, but with padding and calc() you could avoid mediaquerie and set an average padding on one side , looking alike a margin:0 auto averageCalc()Value;  idea: https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/poBxOvY

sadly none of these worked for me. adam - yes, that's similar but my start point are containers that aren't centered bu e.g.  have margin set10% from the right, or 8% from he left. it's when they hit the sides of the vewiport at irregular moment (as browser width is made smaller, that they should set margin to 0 so they dont get cut off.

g-cyrillus thank you for your example. i couldnt replicate that with my code in a way that doesn't cause the boxes to strangely scale when you make them wider. it seemed to do a nice job when the browser width was made small tho.

if anyone can kindly take a look at my original code, be much appercaited, thanks all

hello, your snippet shows your 2 containers centered until they hit the browser's width . Your mediaquerie doesn't seem to do anything , this is why i do not truly understand your goal. Also, what are those 8% expected to be ? 8% of the viewport's width (8vw?) or of the container's width itself ? Sorry if it is obvious to you :)

just made a variant : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/poBxOvY Is that closer to your expected behavior ? i added a shadow on the container , so you can visualize the padding areas

hi g cyrillus, yes that really helps me understand it thank you!!
can i ask - why specifically do we have 8%, the 50w and the pixel dimensions if we have already determined the width of the conatiners on the container divs themselves?
.first-container {
padding-left:min(8%, calc(50vw - 400px ))
}
.second-container {
padding-right:min(8%,  calc(50vw - 300px ));

re: your question - the boxes are always meant to be horizontally offset from the center - i was usiong the 8% and the 10% margins to set the containers from the left of the browser edge, or the right edge. it was more a design element

does it need the 8% figure in the code you have?
if it works just with these:
padding-left:min(calc(50vw - 400px ))
}
.second-container {
padding-right:min(calc(50vw - 300px ));
again be super greatafufl if you could help me understand why is it 50vw, and where have the 300px and 400px come from?

You can achieve this by using the CSS calc() function in combination with viewport units vw for viewport width.
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

/* Link styles */
a {
  color: blue; /* Set link color to blue */
  text-decoration: none; /* Remove default underline */
}

/* Hover and active link styles */
a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: underline; /* Underline link on hover, click, or focus */
}

.container {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Include padding and border in element's total width and height */
  width: calc(100% - 40px); /* Set width to 100% minus the total horizontal padding */
  max-width: 800px; /* Set max-width to 800px */
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column; /* Change flex direction to column */
  position: relative; /* Add position relative */
  margin-top: 0px; /* Add margin-top for spacing */
}

/* Custom CSS for text boxes */
.textbox {
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px; /* Add margin-top for spacing */
  margin-left: auto; /* Align to the right */
  margin-bottom: 0px; /* Add margin-bottom for spacing */
  text-align: left; /* Align text to the left */
}

/* Media query for positioning and scaling the second container */
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .first-container {
    margin-left: calc(8vw - 20px); /* Position from the left */
  }
  .second-container {
    margin-right: calc(8vw - 20px); /* Position from the right */
  }
}


thank you again. i really apprecaite it! again can i ask here - why did we select these specific numbers: calc(8vw - 20px);, the 8 and the 20 for both. and why must we subtract the 20px?

@hellofromlondon The calc(8vw - 20px) expression is used to calculate the left and right margins of your containers in a responsive manner. The 8vw represents 8% of the viewport width. The vw unit stands for “viewport width” and is equal to 1% of the width of the viewport. So 8vw is 8% of the viewport width.
20px: This is the total horizontal padding (left and right) of your containers. The 20px value was chosen to give your containers’ content some space from the edges of the containers.

1 final question!
can we set this calc for all containers rather than set it each time?
margin left / right will be different for each container, but is there a way we don't have to manually update calc each time?
.
@media (min-width: 768px) { /* Adjust this value based on when you want to apply these styles /
.c-cookbook {     margin-right: 5%; / 5% from the right /
width: calc(95% - 10px); / Calculate width dynamically /   }
.c-gap {     margin-left: 8%; / 8% from the left /
width: calc(92% - 10px); / Calculate width dynamically */   }
}

Yes, you can use CSS variables to use globally to replace each calc() function. You still have to place each variable where you would like it, but it would be easier placing a variable then re-writing the code each time for different elements. It would look like this:
:root {   --container-margin: 8vw; }
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {   .first-container {     margin-left: calc(var(--container-margin) - 20px); /* Position from the left */   }   .second-container {     margin-right: calc(var(--container-margin) - 20px); /* Position from the right */   } }

ah it didnt work for me.your solution with % worked better over using vw - it cuts images off (when browser width is small). i'll try figure out if there's a way to simplify using %calc so it doesnt have to be rewritten each time:
@media (min-width: 768px) { /* Adjust this value based on when you want to apply these styles /
.c-cookbook {     margin-right: 5%; / 5% from the right /
width: calc(95% - 10px); / Calculate width dynamically /   }
.c-gap {     margin-left: 8%; / 8% from the left /
width: calc(92% - 10px); / Calculate width dynamically */   }
}

@hellofromlondon Yeah, I personally don't use variables that much, as I use VS code for most of my projects, so I have extensions installed that help me put a block or snippet of code wherever necessary. I could have messed something up when I mentioned the variables. Variables do work, but work in a very specific way. To be honest I don't like the way CSS variables work. I would honestly use a framework like SCSS or SASS instead of CSS variables but that is my opinion :)
